# TinyMCE editor doesn't show during message composition roundcube

Tags: email, tinymce, html-email, roundcube

I am working on a new project on roundcube and after long hours of sleepless nights managed to get all the necessary software installed and configured roundcube on the test server. I am able to log into the server and send and receive messages, but the problem is that I am unable to see the TinyMCE editor when I am composing the message.

The following parameter is enabled in the main.inc.php file:

// compose html formatted messages by default
$rcmail_config['htmleditor'] = TRUE;

but still I am unable to find the editor. When I view the source of the loaded compose page, I am able to see the tiny_mce javascript file loaded which makes it even more confusing why the editor is not shown..

Am I missing something?? Please help...

Comment: please show us your tinymce init function (the configuration), i somwhow got the feeling you do not have one....

Comment: Can you please tell me where can I find the init function()?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for your information, but I tried what you said, it didn't work :(

However, the actual issue was that the tiny_mce editor js file was not found on the server. This I was able to confirm once I was the apache error logs. I uploaded the tiny_mce editor js file and now I am able to see the editor during composing a message.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call a bit of javascript to amek the editor appear.
Ideally there is something like the following script on your page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
tinyMCE.init({
        // General options
        mode : "textareas",
        theme : "advanced"
});
</script>
```

This will transform all textareas on your page into tinymce instances.

There are many configuration options which allow to define what buttons you want to see where and much more...
[Here is a list](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration) of all possible configuration options.